# How to replace an image?

Tags: javascript

I'm learning to use APIs and I use a public API for getting images.

I noticed that most of the images end with `large.jpg` and they have small versions, so I used `replace()` to auto resize them:

```
img.replace("large", "small");
```

The problem is that not all of the image URLs end with large.jpg or small.jpg. Some are just "1091034.jpg" and it gives me `GET 404`.

Is it possible to ask with JavaScript to recognize this case and replace with my placeholder image URL?

Comment: I don't follow. If the string on which you're running the replacement `large` -> `small` does not actually contain `large` in the first place, nothing will happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use match instead

```
       function changeImage() {
            var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
            if (image.src.match("large")) {
                image.src = "small.jpg";
            }
            else {
                image.src = "smaller.jpg"; //OR Ignore
            }
        }
```

Read [here](https://techfunda.com/howto/444/changing-of-images) for further notes.